# How to execute Model Method name in where query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have users table that has `first_name` and `last_name`. On my user index page, there is a text field for `first_name` and `last_name` search.

If I search with either `first_name` or `last_name` it works fine. But if I enter the full name in the text field then it doesn't give me any results

My `User` model

```
def fullname
  first_name + last_name
end
```

My Query

```
User.where("lower(first_name) like ? or lower(last_name) like ?", "%#{params[:fullname].downcase}%", "%#{params[:fullname].downcase}%")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the two names when searching:

```
User.where(
  "(LOWER(first_name) || ' ' || LOWER(last_name)) LIKE ?",
  "%#{params[:fullname].downcase}%"
)
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer is working but still is any way to search with model method name ?

Comment: @RoRDeveloper, no. Unless someone implements a database that can load and execute random Ruby code just as effectively as SQL.

Comment: @RoRDeveloper, you can load all users in memory and call the method on each individual user, but you shouldn't do it if your application is ever to be used in production by more than a few users.